# How to design simply drag and drop system with getting position

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I wonder how Can I achieve simply drag and drop system in my Universal application. I want for example drag some object from list (control or picture) and drop in any position in form. And the best if application could get position of this control later (margins, etc.).

Comment: Do you have specifed panel that will hold droped objects? Or you just want to left them on any position in window?

Comment: Run [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlDragAndDrop).

Comment: @sTrenat: No, for now I don't have. At the beginning it can be just left them on any position